# query_vars empty when using custom url with custom rewrite rule

Tags: wp-query, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to pass custom url parameters to pretty urls using

```
add_rewrite_tag('%product%', '([0-9/]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^sign-up/product/([0-9/]+)?$','index.php?pagename=sign-up&product=$matches[2]','top');
```

and while I can go to **/sign-up/product/60/** successfully

the `$wp_query->query_var['product']` variable seems to be empty

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong...is there anything else I need to do again? I've flushed the rules several times just to be sure but no dice.

Answer (score 3):

You only have one capture group, the ID is in `matches[1]`, there is no `matches[2]`.

EDIT-

Here is the working version I tested in the 2016 theme. I created a page with slug `sign-up`, added the following to `functions.php`, then visited the Permalinks Settings page to flush rewrite rules. The value passed to `product` is available in the template via `get_query_var( 'product' );`

```
function wpd_product_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%product%', '([0-9/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^sign-up/product/([0-9/]+)?$',
        'index.php?pagename=sign-up&product=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_product_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Hmmmm....I HAD actually tried that first and I kept getting 404. When I tried the [2] I got the page and the variable but the value is just empty. ....wierd. Is there anything else I should check on?( Yes I flush the cache/ rules regularly)

Comment: See edit above. I've tested it and it's working as expected. Make sure your page is a root page and doesn't have a parent assigned. If the page is a child of another page, then `pagename` must reflect the parent/child slug path. Also verify that `product` is unique, there is no other plugin or code that's using the `product` query var for other purposes (like Woocommerce, for example).

Comment: @Milo I lost HOURS of my life lost to trying to figure out why my rewrite rule/tag was not working, and I finally found your comment about **making sure the page does not have a parent assigned** (or adding the full path to ?pagename if it does). Such a crucial piece of information, THANK YOU!